# Filter array of objects by range of dates

Tags: javascript, datetime, filter, range

Say I have an array of objects like on the picture:

[image: Array of objects]

Each object contains property `ShipperPickupDate` with a string value made from date object by calling `toLocaleTimeString('en-US')` method.

What I need is to filter this array of objects by the date range. Say I want to get new array containing objects filtered by `shipperPickupDate` in range `from 2/10/2020 to 3/18/2020`. Is there any method or suggestions?

Sorry for not providing any code. I'm still in searching of a proper way to do this so any suggestions are highly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: you will need to use Array.prototype.map()  to create your date object from the string values.  Then pipe this through Array.prototype.filter() to get the date range you need.

Comment: `let newArr = this.loadsFiltered.forEach(el => {
      return (
        el.shipperPickupDate >= this.date1 && el.shipperPickupDate <= this.date2
      );
    });`

Would that work?

Comment: You should use a library like `momentjs` to deal with date, it helps a lot and it has a function `isBetween` that you can use.

Comment: never heard of that lib before, will give it a try, thank you!

Comment: @Madcap another tips I can give you, do not forget that `toLocaleTimeString` gives you a date based on locale timezone, could be a good idea to get your dates "rawly" to get UTC time too.

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: Now I do it like that: let date1 = new Date(this.date1)
this.date1 contain string like '1/11/2019' and same for date2
then I compare two newly created variables and it works

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
Just compare date in callback of filter function then it will return filtered array.